# How to fire tab key event?

Tags: java, swing, awt

How do we fire a <kbd>tab</kbd> key pressed event deliberately in Java? I also want to know how to fire a <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>tab</kbd> key pressed event programmatically in Java.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The following example shows how to simulate mouse and key presses in Java using [`java.awt.Robot`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) class.

```
try {
    Robot robot = new Robot();
    
    // Simulate a mouse click
    robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
    robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
    
    // Simulate a key press
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
} catch (AWTException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Edited my post to do the SHIFT + TAB Key Press.

Comment: Thanks alot, tab can be managed by VK_TAB, buthow do i generate "shift+tab".?

Comment: shift+tab is `SHIFT` pressed, then `TAB` pressed, then these keys released

Comment: @sasidhar @Valentin : Valentin has been quicker than me, thx and +1 :) I edited my post to do a SHIFT + TAB KeyPress. VK_TAB for Tab, and VK_SHIFT for Shift Key Press. You can find all the KeyEvents here : http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html

Answer (score 7):

If what you really want is just to navigate to the next component, you can do:

```
KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().focusNextComponent();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Robot`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html#keyPress%28int%29) class for this